# Submit handler doesn't work correctly in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, submit, onchange, onsubmit

my friends I'm making a react class that gets an input value when the form is submitted, to send a get request using `axios` but **i got result after the second click**

```
class SearchForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {inputtermvalue: "",spaces_list: "",spacesname: ""};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
  }
  updateInputValue(evt){
    this.setState({inputtermvalue: evt.target.value});
  }
  handleSubmit(){
    this.setState({spaces_list: $("input.sp-autocomplete-spaces").val()});
    this.sendGetRequest();
  }
  sendGetRequest(){
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
        axios
      .get("/rest/1.0/term/search", {
        params: {
                     query: this.state.inputtermvalue, 
                     spaces: this.state.spaces_list
        },
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    })
    .then(({data}) => {
```

Comment: are you sure it took two clicks and you didn't just click it a second time while waiting for the get request to resolve?

Comment: also dont u need to bind the methods

Comment: where are you checking the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is an **asynchronous** call, so you can't expect it to immediately finish before continuing. In your code here:

```
handleSubmit(){
    this.setState({spaces_list: $("input.sp-autocomplete-spaces").val()});
    this.sendGetRequest();
}
```

You are updating state and then calling a method that uses that new state value. What **could be** happening is that you are calling `this.sendGetRequest` before your state has finished updating.

You should use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook to make sure that state is finished updating before calling `this.sendGetRequest`:

```
handleSubmit () {
    this.setState({
        spaces_list: $("input.sp-autocomplete-spaces").val()
    });
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    if(prevState.spaces_list !== this.state.spaces_list) {
        this.sendGetRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: this works only when spaces_list != "" but for me i would like to send request when it is null

Comment: Then you can remove the if check and just always trigger `this.sendGetRequest`